# Discord.js Cannot read property 'activities' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have the following discord.js code as part of my discord bot :

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  let member = newPresence.member

  if (member.id === '471501478071238656') {
    if (oldPresence.activities !== newPresence.activities) {

      if (newPresence.status === "online") {
        client.channels.cache.get('860885953765048342').messages.fetch('860892525996539905').then(msg => {
          msg.edit('Online')
        })
      } else if (newPresence.status === "idle") {
        client.channels.cache.get('860885953765048342').messages.fetch('860892525996539905').then(msg => {
          msg.edit('Online')
        })
      } else if (newPresence.status === "dnd") {
        client.channels.cache.get('860885953765048342').messages.fetch('860892525996539905').then(msg => {
          msg.edit('Online')
        })
      } else if (newPresence.status === "offline") {
        client.channels.cache.get('860885953765048342').messages.fetch('860892525996539905').then(msg => {
          msg.edit('Offline')
        })
      }
    }
  } else if (member.id === '578054170628718612') {
    if (oldPresence.activities !== newPresence.activities) {

      if (newPresence.status === "online") {
        client.channels.cache.get('860885953765048342').messages.fetch('860892636235694080').then(msg => {
          msg.edit('Online')
        })
      } else if (newPresence.status === "idle") {
        client.channels.cache.get('860885953765048342').messages.fetch('860892636235694080').then(msg => {
          msg.edit('Online')
        })
      } else if (newPresence.status === "dnd") {
        client.channels.cache.get('860885953765048342').messages.fetch('860892636235694080').then(msg => {
          msg.edit('Online')
        })
      } else if (newPresence.status === "offline") {
        client.channels.cache.get('860885953765048342').messages.fetch('860892636235694080').then(msg => {
          msg.edit('Offline')
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

however, when ran (or when one of the users status changes, not entirely sure) the code always gives the following error :

/home/runner/Awow/index.js:30
if (oldPresence.activities !== newPresence.activities) {
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'activities' of undefined

How can I fix this?

Notes :
client is defined at the start of the code (not shown)

Comment: do u have presense intent enabled for the bot? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Comment: Yes, presence intent is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when this is called newPresence is always a Presence object but the oldPresence variable can be undefined or a Presence object.

I don't know exactly when oldPresence is undefined as I cant find it in the documentation, but I'd assume its when the user was previously offline.

Edit: Found the documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate)